# Why I am Getting Error Message from WebPage "Undefined"

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

For Displaying Message I have AddedOnEndCallback() function which is working Fine As expected But while clicking New Button or Cancel Button its showing Error Message Like Undefined I check every Where I mean On network Tab as well as in Console Windows but no any error i found where i am doing Mistake Please Suggest me:

Edit:

I have added:

```
if (gvc.cpInsertNote == undefined ) {
                // Ignore
            }
```

So for now Undefined Message is not Appearing First Time But Later always showing same message for every Click Please Suggest me where i am doing Wrong ?

ASPX:

Grid View :

```
 <Templates>
   <DetailRow>
     <dx:ASPxGridView ID="dgCustomers" runat="server" KeyFieldName="CustomerLineItemID" OnBeforePerformDataSelect="dgCustomers_BeforePerformDataSelect"
        OnDataBinding="dgCustomers_DataBinding" ClientInstanceName="gvc"
        Width="100%" OnRowDeleting="dgCustomers_RowDeleting" OnRowInserting="dgCustomers_RowInserting"
        OnRowUpdating="dgCustomers_RowUpdating" CellStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
       <ClientSideEvents EndCallback="OnEndCallback" />
           <Columns>
              .......
                .......
```

Js.

```
 function OnEndCallback() {
        if (gvc.cpInsertNote == undefined || gvc.IsNewItemEditing() ||gvc.IsEditing()) {
            // Egnore
        }

        else {
            if (gvc.cpInsertNote != "") {
                alert(gvc.cpInsertNote);
            }
        }
        //return;
    }
```

.Cs

```
  if (CustomerCount > 0)
        {
            ((ASPxGridView)sender).JSProperties["cpInsertNote"] = "Duplicate Entries Not Allowed";
            e.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }
```

I am ABle to display Message But while clicking New Button of grid View its showing "Undefined"  why ?

[image]

Comment: what's `gvc` here? the code you have shared does not have much to explain what you are doing and what's the issue you are facing

Comment: gvc is  ClientInstanceName as you can see in Grid view Code ClientInstanceName="gvc"

Comment: Looks like `alert(gvc.cpInsertNote);` is executed and `gvc.cpInsertNote` is not defined.. that's why you are getting `undefined` in the alert. Did you debug and check if `((ASPxGridView)sender).JSProperties["cpInsertNote"] ......`  code is executed?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I want to display a message if user Enters duplicate values for that i am calling this function as we know in ASPxGrid View we can not display Message by using " ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "message", "alert('message');", true);"

Comment: If `CustomerCount` is zero, the `cpInsertNote` property doesn't get set. Is that the issue?

Comment: @cdd I think Chetan wanted to you to answer their specific queries, rather than reply telling us information which is already in your question... If you don't understand what you're being asked, then please say so.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yes I  can see While debugging ((ASPxGridView)sender).JSProperties["cpInsertNote"] .. code is executed

Comment: @DavidG then how can set that value ?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya at the time of cancel or new click i am getting undefined but after this message i am also getting my original message that is after ((ASPxGridView)sender).JSProperties["cpInsertNote"]  executed